# How to divide a list by value and join back in original order?

Tags: python

For example, if I have a list of `[1,2,3,1,1,2]`, I want to

1. divide it by values, e.g., to `[1,1,1], [2,2], [3]`,
2. perform an action (e.g., plus index, `[1,1,1]` becomes `[1,2,3]`, and `[2,2]` becomes `[2,3]`),
   and 3) rejoin with the original index, yielding `[1,2,3,2,3,3]`. Is there an efficient way I could do so?

Comment: This sounds like [*XY problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) for me. Could you add some details how you want to apply solution of this particular problem?

Comment: Not completely clear, but using a `Counter` object seems natural.

Comment: Your example input has a built-in coincidence. Can you show the expected output if your input is `[1,3,2,1,1,2]` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.count` with `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
import itertools, collections as cl
def group(l):
   d, d1 = cl.OrderedDict(), cl.defaultdict(itertools.count)
   for i in l:
      d.setdefault(i, []).append(i+next(d1[i]))
   return list(itertools.chain(*d.values()))

print(group([1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2]))
print(group([1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that does not import any libraries.

```
l = [1,2,3,1,1,2]
n = []
c = -1

#group
#count how many instances of a number there are in a list
#list.remove(num) removes a single instance of a number, so using the previous, we loop it and delete all instances
#before deleting the instance we add it to an array as many times as there are instances of it
#c variable is a counter, whenever we are done "transporting" instances, we change the array in which we place the new instances
#all of the said arrays are contained within one array, that way we can use .append([]) to add as many new arrays for as many instances as we want
while True:
    try:
        num = l[0]
        c += 1
    except IndexError:
        break
    
    n.append([])

    for _ in range(l.count(num)):
        n[c].append(num)
        l.remove(num)

#plus index
for i in range(len(n)):
    for j in range(len(n[i])):
        n[i][j] += j

#join
for i in range(len(n)):
    l.extend(n[i])

#print
print(l)
```